# How to set formatter function for tooltip in highcharts using react with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, highcharts, tooltip, formatter

I have a chart with `columnrange` type which should display some timelines. I have my time in UTC. It displays well on yAxis because of property '`type: "datetime"`', but in tooltip it displays time in seconds. I want to format it.

I was trying to use constructions like this:

```
formatter() {

}
```

or like this:

```
formatter: function() {

}
```

but they are not allowed here and all I get is an error "`'type' is declared here`"

The only available way to use formatter for me is:

```
formatter: (ctx) => {
            
}
```

Where ctx refers to `Highcharts.tooltips`. But, arrow function does not allow me to get the `y` value by using `this` keyword. Please, tell me, what should I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying different ways to use function() in order to access `this.y` and found the solution:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function(ctx) {
              
  }
}
```

All the ways works fine, I just need to pass context variable to function, either `formatter(ctx): {}` or `formatter: function(ctx) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below notation with typed function parameters:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function(
    this: Highcharts.TooltipFormatterContextObject,
    tooltip: Highcharts.Tooltip
) {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-ms2duw

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.TooltipFormatterCallbackFunction

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is useful too